# Intel NCS2 suddenly disappears adfter multiple successfull inferences

Tags: usb, openvino

I'm running a Raspberry PI 4B Buster environment with all recommended OpenVino dependencies.

I'm trying to put together an object detection pipeline, with multiple object detectors, and multiple inference requests per object detector.

The problem occurs after some time, 10m to 10h, the program doesn't crash, but I can see on the pipeline, that inference stops to happen. Running `lsusb` the Myriad device is missing.

---

First thought was temperature issues, but the device doesn't reach above 42.5 °C.

In `dmesg` output there's no sign of undervoltage issue.

---

I'd need your help to investigate the problem, the things I've tried so far are:

- Different Python version (3.6, 3.7, 3.8)
- Different OpenVINO version (2021/3, 2021/4)
- Different Raspberry Device.

---

The environment contains of:
|||
|-|-|
| OS | Raspbian Buster 10 |
| Python | 3.7.3 |
| OpenVINO | 2021.4.2-3974-e2a469a3450-releases/2021/4 |

Comment: which code did you use to run this with for 10 hours? Did you refer to the official OpenVINO samples as a reference?

Comment: From the official package I used "object_detection_demo.py" from the "demos" folder in the official release as a base for my script.
The only significant modification is the use of multiple models.
The input is a camera feed or a looped video.

Answer (score 0):

The OpenVINO [Action Recognition Python Demo](https://docs.openvino.ai/latest/omz_demos_action_recognition_demo_python.html?) is the best reference for you since it uses multiple models and the inference uses input video.

Each step in this demo implements PipelineSteps interface by creating a class derived from PipelineSteps base class. It has been designed to properly function with the supported hardware (CPU,GPU, HDDL or MYRIAD).

Your issue could be caused by your modified code (maybe some error handler is required, some sequence of processes is improper, etc) or caused by the NCS2 device itself.

Try to confirm the device availability:

1. NCS2 was detected after rebooting and running lsusb - the NCS2 is in a good condition. It's just that sometimes, there are some underneath services halted/incomplete, which results in this issue.
2. NCS2 was **not** detected after rebooting and running lsusb - it could be a device issue/malfunction and if still within the warranty period, you may ask for a replacement.